# Angularjs Formly - Select field passing String:value to Google sheet

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I'm using Angularjs Formly and am posting data to a google sheet. Passing text field values is fine but my SELECT fields are posting as "string:'product 1'" to the sheet, 'product 1' is what I need to see in the sheet. Would appreciate any suggestions to correct this. Thanks.

Controller:

```
key: 'product type',
            type: 'select',
            templateOptions: {
                label: 'Product Select',
                options: [
                    {
                        name: 'product 1',
                        value: 'product 1',
                        group: 'Products'
                    },

                    {
                        name: 'product 2',
                        value: 'product 2',
                        group: 'Products'
                    },
```

HTML

```
<formly-form model="vm.products" fields="vm.productsFields"   form="vm.productsForm">
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example: http://help.angular-formly.com/ ? That would make it easier to know what is going on...

Comment: Could you make an example that actually runs with step-by-step reproduction instructions? You can use http://help.angular-formly.com as a template to get started.

Comment: Kent, here is a working example, I updated the first field value to select and am getting the same results.  http://jsbin.com/subehe/edit?html,output

Comment: Here is the sheet collecting the post: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RRwm3WwnfXbk5rXmttyi2W6MR3DZfvQOnyOPpAY6LC8/edit#gid=953228773

Comment: How's this? https://jsbin.com/subehe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Not seeing a difference. Still posting as string:product 1

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I forgot to clone it and save my copy. I've answered with the fix.

Comment: I see the syntax error in my example jsbin, fixing it hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: Seemed to work for me...

Comment: I'm still only seeing "string:product 1" in my spreadsheet entries. I should be receiving "product 1", minus the quotes of course.

Comment: Ah, I don't think that bit is angular-formly related. You're going to have to figure out why it's posting like that. But formly is populating the model correctly...

Comment: Hmm ok. For what it's worth, I'm not having issues passing any of the other fields as text. Standard bootstrap form is also posting select values without a problem.  Seems to be an issue with the way the select value is being handled somewhere.

Comment: @kentcdodds Here's my post parameters to show that the issue is not related to the way google sheets is handling the post: Post Params:
key: 'formly_1_select_productSelect_0' value: 'string:product 1'
key: 'formly_1_textarea_story_1' value: 'more text'
key: 'formly_1_checkbox_awesome_2' value: 'on'
key: 'formly_1_custom_custom_4' value: 'more text'
key: 'formly_1_template_exampleDirective_5' value: 'more text'
Empty post body.

Comment: In addition I cloned your demo example and am getting the same results which you can see at : http://jsbin.com/hipawi/edit?html,js,output  After posting my results are at: http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2015/07/18/07.56.32624312946

Comment: @kentcdodds Can you recommend a solution now that Ive demonstrated that the select value in Formly is posting string:string using your default form demo code?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I honestly have no idea why it's doing this. I would actually recommend attempting to post the form via ajax using angular's built-in `$http` service. That way you could make sure that you have control over the data you're sending...

Comment: Yes, I've started looking into using services. I'll let you know if I have any luck going that route. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's [the solution](https://jsbin.com/haceji/edit?html,js,output)

The problem was that you had:

```
<form  method="POST"" action="https://docs.google.com/a/elementalled.com/forms/d/1JttrExGbBGB82d54Pq-74oFKQHKHSTfq2pBKw3QiGRU/formResponse?" ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" novalidate>
```

When it should have been

```
<form  method="POST" action="https://docs.google.com/a/elementalled.com/forms/d/1JttrExGbBGB82d54Pq-74oFKQHKHSTfq2pBKw3QiGRU/formResponse?" ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" novalidate>
```

Notice the two quotes on POST... That's invalid HTML and messed everything else up...